# Why Jackson serializing super class as separate object?

Tags: java, spring, jackson

Suppose I have below Cassandra entities.

```
@Entity
class Person {
    private String name;
    // getter and setter
}

@Entity
class Job {
    private String title;
    // getter and setter
}

class PersonWrapper extends Person {
    private Job job; 
    // getter and setter
}
```

And API is giving:

```
{
    "name": "rick",
    "job": {
        "title": "programmer"
    },
    "person": {
        "name": "rick",
        "job": {
            "title": "programmer"
        }
    }
}
```

My temporary solution is to use *JsonIgnoreProperties* on wrapper class. Is there any solution to eliminate the duplicate object?

Comment: It's unclear what you are doing to have such JSON.

Comment: Your classes here do not represent the JSON. So either your JSON is wrong or the classes you posted are wrong.

Comment: @cassiomolin Basically I want to wrap every object related to Person instance in PersonWrapper class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson maps the fields of a JSON to the equal fields in a Java object by matching the names of the JSON fields and fields from your class without "get" and "set" (you have to  have getters and setters in your serialization classes).
In your example you need to create class like that:

```
@Getter
@Setter
class CommonClass {
    String name;
    Job job; 
    Person person;
}
@Getter
@Setter
class Job {
    String title;
}
@Getter
@Setter
class Person {
    String name;
    Job job; 
}
```